# XMLHttpRequest working locally, but not on server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In short, I have a project which runs fine locally, but once uploaded to my server, my one XMLHttpRequest fails miserably. The relative path to the XML (.tmx in this case) file being loaded is definitely correct. Any help in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

The location of the project is [www.jorum.se/fancypants/](http://jorum.se/fancypants/), and the code in question in [game.js](http://jorum.se/fancypants/game.js) (line 22).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML document on the server is not being served with the `text/xml` content-type and so the XmlHttpRequest object is not treating the response as XML, which means that the `responseXML` property is not being set.  Note that the `responseText` property does contain the XML text.

Fix the HTTP server to return the correct content-type.

Comment: Or, override the XMLHttpRequest object to force it to be parsed as XML if you can't fix the server.

Comment: Overriding the mime type seemed to fix it. On to the next problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's making the AJAX request fine from what I see. By my reckoning, your problem are these lines:

```
var xmldoc = req.responseXML;
    var mapwidth = xmldoc.documentElement.getAttribute("width");
```

xmldoc is null, thus it's throwing the following error:

```
game.js:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
```

I'm also curious as to why you're going through the effort of manually making your own XMLHttpRequest object when you've already loaded jQuery anyway. Why not just use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? You could set your parameters to include a `dataType` of `xml`, which might coerce it in to parsing it even if you aren't setting your HTTP headers properly.

Comment: Basically I'm just looking for as little overhead as possible, I was just using jQuery for aesthetics. But I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: considering that some browsers implement XHR differently, it seems like a fairly low cost to pay for not only cross-browser compatibility, but readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at javascript errors in your favorite browser?  I see an error on line 22 of `game.js` which looks like it's because your responseXML isn't what you were expecting it to be and thus xmldoc isn't getting initialized the way you want it to be.  Crack open a debugger (Chrome inspector or Firebug in Firefox) and see for yourself what is failing.  If it were me, I'd set a breakpoint on line 21 of game.js and look at the req object to see what it's telling me about the last transaction (errors, other data, etc...).

See the decription of responseXML [here on Mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest).  Possible reasons for a null `responseXML` are server doesn't apply the `text/xml` Content-Type header or an XML parsing error.  If your server isn't setting the right MIME type, you can force it to parse as XML with `overrideMimeType()`.

Comment: The script waits, because the XMLHttpRequest open() function is set to work syncronously: `open("GET", "maps/testmap.tmx", false);` (3rd parameter)

Comment: Ah, OK.  Wasn't expecting synchronous ajax calls because they are so user-unfriendly.  Then, the problem is that your xmldoc is null.  You should set a breakpoint on line 21 and see what the responseXML is.

Comment: Me neither, just wanted to let you know. Btw. the answer from cdhowie is correct that's why `responseXML` is not defined.

Comment: @stewe - I'd agree that's the most likely cause, but unless you've seen the server response, we're still just guessing.